# Edit an existing Pastebin document via API

Tags: http, lua, pastebin

I am trying to write a function in LUA to edit my pastebin code.

I can use this code to make a HTTP post:

> http.post(string url, string postData [, table headers])

I can also use this code for a HTTP get:

> http.get(string url [, table headers])

on the Pastebin website *https://pastebin.com/api* are information about using the API.
I am not sure, if this website can help me to solve my problem.

Does someone know how to fill the headers table?

**this is the program i tried:**

```
headers = {}
headers["api_dev_key"]= 'myDevKey...'; // your api_developer_key
headers["api_paste_code"]   = 'my edited text'; // your paste text
headers["api_paste_private"] = '0'; // 0=public 1=unlisted 2=private
headers["api_paste_name"] = 'justmyfilename.php'; // name or title of your paste
headers["api_paste_expire_date"] = '10M';
headers["api_paste_format"] = 'php';
headers["api_user_key"] = ''; // if an invalid or expired api_user_key is used, an error will spawn. If no api_user_key is used, a guest paste will be created
headers["api_paste_name"] = myPastebinName;
headers["api_paste_code"] = myPastebinPassword;
http.get("https://pastebin.com/edit/dQMDfbkM", headers)
```

unfortunately this is not working and on the pastebin API help site is no exsample for editing a paste. just for creating a new one.

for me it is also not clear if I have to use post or get

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no API for editing pastes directly.

You can only delete old paste and create new with updated text.

Comment: I can not believe that, because I think, that a browser is also just using HTTP and with a browser it is still possible. I just need to fill the table correctly... But thanks for your response. before I upVote this answer I'll wait  a bit and try again

Comment: @Thomas Browser doesn't use API. Of course, you can emulate browser behavior, but it's not so easy. I found JavaScript module that uses API were it's possible + can edit pastes just like browser do: [better-pastebin.js](https://github.com/Hydrothermal/better-pastebin/blob/master/lib/better-pastebin.js) ([docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-pastebin)). You can try to reimplement part of code that edit pastes to Lua...

Comment: If it's not possible with pastebin, is there another paste service that allows editing an existing paste via an HTTP API?

Comment: @frakman1 **Github Gists** - they are basically just github repos that you can push to using local git